# Удаление элемента из строки используя регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Как удалить элемент из строки с помощью библиотеки `re`

Вот мой код:

```
a = 'I like (TV) and (1988)'
re.sub(r'TV\)','',a)
```

И всё работает правильно, кроме того, что остаётся одна дужка:

```
'I like ( and (1988)'
```

Как сделать так, чтобы лишняя дужка удалялась вместе с содержимым в дужках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 'I like (TV) and (1988)'
print(re.sub(r'\(TV\)','',a))
```